# How to slide over other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many divs (3 in a row), and I want to slide them on mouse hover. Now all divs are moving and its not looking nice. What I want, is to slide hovered div (change its height, and stay over other divs), but other divs to stay on the same position.

So just `.desc` will be shown between "Some text" and "Price".

**HTML:**

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="list-new">
        <p>Some text...</p>
        <p class="desc">Some hidden text...<br />Another line of hidden text...</p>
        <p class="price">9.99 €</p>
    </div>
    ... <!-- other divs here -->
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list-new").mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(this).find(".desc").slideDown();
    });

    $(".list-new").mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).find(".desc").slideUp();
    });
});
```

**CSS**:

```
#list {
    width: 320px;
}

.list-new {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 98px;
    min-height: 80px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.list-new:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.list-new p.desc {
    display: none;
    background-color: black
    width: 98px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.list-new p.price {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98px;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Updated jsFiddle:**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/04pdm5ku/7/)

Comment: Hm. I would most likely do this programatically - possibly by giving them all `position: absolute`, using logic to array them in a grid this way, making sure to increment to their `z-index`.

Comment: Yes, that could be probably only solution. I was hoping to do it somehow with `CSS` and `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally did it, using `clone()` and some other jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list-new").mouseenter(function() {
        var clone = $(this).clone(),
            pos   = $(this).position(),
            id    = $(this).attr('data-id');

        clone.find('.desc').css('display', 'block');

        clone
            .attr('id', 'list_over_' + id)
            .addClass('list-new-hovered')
            .css({
                'display': 'none',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'left': pos.left,
                'top': pos.top,
                'z-index': 10
            })
            .appendTo($(this).parent())
            .on('mouseleave', function() {
                $('#list_over_' + $(this).attr('data-id')).stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            })
            .stop(true, true)
            .fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

[jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/04pdm5ku/9/)

Comment: Glad you found it, was just going to suggest an overlay solution too  :D  http://jsfiddle.net/04pdm5ku/10/

Answer (score 5):

You can add :

```
.desc {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

To your css file !

Comment: This is nice solution, but not working as expected. Because there are also other elements. I updated my jsFiddle.

Comment: I updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04pdm5ku/8/). There is one last issue, on mouse out, desc is hided while closing, you can write a callback in jQuery to edit z-index (`$(this).find('.desc').css('z-index', '0');`)

Comment: That looks better, but still there is huge empty space between "Some text" and "Hidden text".

Comment: I finally did it (as seen in my answer), anyway, thanks for help - http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/04pdm5ku/9/

Answer (score 1):

Is better with pure-css code. And I recommend to you to put out floats and change it by the properties made to position elements in layout. Float is a bad practice very extended in order to apply compatibility with IE6 / IE7 , but is not neccesary in 21st century.

If you use display: inline-block instead of float:left, the divs doesn't move of their position (including vertical-align: top for example).

Comment: I am viewing your jsfiddle and my answer is not related. Sorry for this. But I comment you one thing, you can achieve this with two techniques: Or control negative margin-bottom when slideToggle() is running, or you can only archieve this with absolute positioning of the elements.

Comment: I finally did it (as seen in my answer), anyway, thanks for help - http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/04pdm5ku/9/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: absolute` from `.list-new p.price`, since you want it to be moved during `slideDown()`.

Use jQuery to wrap each `.list-new`'s children in a `div` with absolute positioning and decreasing `z-index`:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.list-new').each(function(i) {
  $(this).children().wrapAll('<div class="abs" style="z-index:'+(999-i)+'"/>');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1ap7pws/2/)

Comment: Also nice solution, just add there `stop(true, true)`, because move for couple second fast over all elements ;-)

Comment: Do you mean `$(this).find(".desc").slideDown().stop(true,true);`?  If you don't want to show the animation, you could just do `$(this).find(".desc").fadeIn();` or `$(this).find(".desc").show();`.

Comment: I have one problem applying it on the website - its firing `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` repeatly, could you please have a look on it? :-( http://www.daydream.sk/masky-na-spanie/darcekove-sety

Comment: Looks like your clone method is currently running.  Do you have a draft version with my code so I could troubleshoot?

Comment: Now its ok. The problem was, that (I dont know why) used `clone(true, true);` instead of `clone();`, but on jsFiddle I have it correctly like `clone();`...

Comment: Thanks, it will look much better, after adding another features.